# Laravel on kubernetes - slow composer vendor autoload (production)

Tags: laravel, kubernetes, composer-php, autoload, vendor

We have set up a kubernetes cluster for our laravel application on google cloud platform.
Containers:

- application code + php-fpm
- apache2
- others not related to the issue

(We run under nginx-ingress-controller but this seems unrelated to the issue)

We run a jmeter stress tests on a simple laravel route that returns "ok" and we noticed terrible  response times.

[image]

Afterwards we run the same test on an index2.php (inside public dir το slide over the framework) which just returns 'ok'.

And we got this result(!):
[image]

After digging we found out that the composer's autoloading stuff cause this slowness.

Any advice on how this could be resolved will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried `composer dump-autoload -a --no-dev`?

Comment: Yes, we tried all the dump-autoload optimizations and composer installed with --optimize-autoloader --classmap-authoritative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. We found out that we had no opcache enabled.
As documented about composer optimize-autoloader:

> On PHP 5.6+, the class map is also cached in opcache which improves the initialization time greatly. If you make sure *opcache is enabled*, then the class map should load almost instantly and then class loading is fast.